# Getting errors in using GeoIP2 in django

Tags: django, ip, geoip2

I am trying to use `GeoIP2` to get user's cities and countries using their IP when they view my website.
I have downloaded 2 files from https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/
, GeoLite Country and GeoLite City Binary/gzip files.
After that I put them in the directory `geoip` inside my projects root.
And there I unzipped them.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAHth.png)
and I have also added this line to my project settings.py file:
`GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')`
but when I try to use GeoIP2 it gives me error:

> GeoIP2Exception at /
>
> Invalid GeoIP country and city data files.

I am using django 2.0.4.

can anybody help me to solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GEOIP2` files : https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

The extension is `.mmdb`, the `.dat` format is for old `GEOIP` and django use `GEOIP2`